# how to add additional value to array

Tags: arrays, database, laravel, model-view-controller, multidimensional-array

i have an array, where all data is calculated by records from matches table:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1342 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    "First team" => & array:6 [▼
      "points" => 3
      "scoredGoals" => 6
      "goalsConceded" => 6
      "wins" => 0
      "loses" => 0
      "draws" => 3
    ]
    "Second team" => array:6 [▶]
    "third team" => array:6 [▶]
    "fourth team" => & array:6 [▶]
  ]
}
```

i need add to array image of each team (from teams table, where column image)
how can i do that?

here is my code from controller, where all data is calculated from matches table:

there is my code which i need edit:

$standings = [];

```
$blank = [
    'points' => 0,
    'scoredGoals' => 0,
    'goalsConceded' => 0,
    'wins' => 0,
    'loses' => 0,
    'draws' => 0,
];

$matches = Match::with('score', 'homeTeam', 'awayTeam')
->whereHas('score', function($query){
    $query->whereNotNull('home_team_score')
        ->whereNotNull('away_team_score');
})
->where('league_id', '=', $league->id)
->get();

foreach ($matches as $match) {

    $homeTeamScore = $match->score->home_team_score;
    $awayTeamScore = $match->score->away_team_score;

    if (! isset($standings[$match->homeTeam->name])) {
        $standings[$match->homeTeam->name] = $blank;
    }

    if (! isset($standings[$match->awayTeam->name])) {
        $standings[$match->awayTeam->name] = $blank;
    }

    $home = &$standings[$match->homeTeam->name];
    $away = &$standings[$match->awayTeam->name];

    $away['scoredGoals'] += $awayTeamScore;
    $home['scoredGoals'] += $homeTeamScore;
    $away['goalsConceded'] += $homeTeamScore;
    $home['goalsConceded'] += $awayTeamScore;
    switch ($homeTeamScore <=> $awayTeamScore) {
        case -1:
            // home lost
            // swap home and away and let it fall through
            $tmpHome = &$home;
            $home = &$away;
            $away = &$tmpHome;
        case 1:
            // home won
            $home['points'] += 3;
            $home['wins']++;
            $away['loses']++;
            break;
        default:
            // draw
            $home['points']++;
            $away['points']++;
            $home['draws']++;
            $away['draws']++;
    }
}

$standings = collect($standings)->sort(function ($one, $other) {
    if ($one['points'] !== $other['points']) {
        return $other['points'] - $one['points'];  // similar to desc
    }

    $oneDelta = $one['scoredGoals'] - $one['goalsConceded'];
    $otherDelta = $other['scoredGoals'] - $other['goalsConceded'];

    return $otherDelta - $oneDelta; // similar to desc
});
return view('admin.leagues.standings')->with([
    'standings' => $standings,
]);
```

Comment: How do you know which element in the array belongs to which team? Is the element key (`First team`) the name of the team in the `teams` table?

Comment: @Unflux, yes,  array element key "First team" is value from  teams table, where value "name"

Comment: well doesn't that code look familiar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with the `key` of each element in your `collection` is the name of your `team` and is stored in the `name` column of your `teams` table, you can map over your collection and add in your `image`.

For example:

```
$images = [
    'First team' => 'first-team.jpg',
    'Second team' => 'second-team.jpg',
    'Third team' => 'third-team.jpg'
];

$teamsWithImages =
    collect([
        "First team" => [
            "points" => 3,
            "scoredGoals" => 6,
            "goalsConceded" => 6,
            "wins" => 0,
            "loses" => 0,
            "draws" => 3,
        ],
        "Second team" => [
            "points" => 3,
            "scoredGoals" => 6,
            "goalsConceded" => 6,
            "wins" => 0,
            "loses" => 0,
            "draws" => 3,
        ],
        "Third team" => [
            "points" => 3,
            "scoredGoals" => 6,
            "goalsConceded" => 6,
            "wins" => 0,
            "loses" => 0,
            "draws" => 3,
        ]
    ])->map(function ($item, $key) use ($images) {

        // You would uncomment this line to retrieve the image
        // from your teams table
        // You also wouldn't need the use ($images) either
        //$item['image'] = Teams::where('name', $key)->first()->image;

        $item['image'] = $images[$key];
        return $item;
    })->all();

dump($teamsWithImages);
```

**Update**

Based on the code you've added, you won't need to `map` you can just add the image in your `foreach`:

```
if (! isset($standings[$match->homeTeam->name])) {
    $standings[$match->homeTeam->name] = $blank;
    $standing[$match->homeTeam->name]['image'] = $match->homeTeam->image;
}

if (! isset($standings[$match->awayTeam->name])) {
    $standings[$match->awayTeam->name] = $blank;
    $standing[$match->awayTeam->name]['image'] = $match->awayTeam->image;
}
```

Alternatively you could still use `map` once you have the `standings` sorted, but you may as well just add the image in with everything else.

```
$standingsWithImages = $standings
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        $item['image'] = Team::where('name', $key)->first()->image;
        return $item;
    })->all();
```

Comment: i added my code below, maybe you can help with editing them. I would be grateful

Comment: @Jetz Best to add it to your original question rather than as an answer buddy.